# How to properly apply stochastic gradient descent to simple neural network?

Tags: python, neural-network, data-science, tensorflow2.0, gradient-descent

Im trying to write NN from scratch to better understand what is going on underneath Keras API. And now I have got problem with applying gradinets to my loss. I believe there is some problem with architecture and my understanding of TF. Basically line with grads returns Nones and hence code returns:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['Variable:0', 'Variable:0', 'Variable:0', 'Variable:0', 'Variable:0', 'Variable:0'].
```

Here is my code. Its very straightforward but I want to do it simply before warping it into model class.

```py
input_shape = x_train.shape[1]
n_hidden_1 = 32
n_hidden_2 = 8
output_shape = 1
epochs = 1

W_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([input_shape,n_hidden_1]))
W_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_hidden_1,n_hidden_2]))
W_output = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_hidden_2,output_shape]))
    
B_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_hidden_1]))
B_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_hidden_2]))
B_output = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([output_shape]))

var_list= [W_1, W_2, W_output, B_1, B_2, B_output]

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)


for epoch in range(epochs):
    
    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(x_train, dtype=tf.float32)
    size = input_tensor.shape[0]
    
    labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train, dtype=tf.float32)
    labels = tf.reshape(labels, (size,1))
    
    #1_layer
    layer_1 = tf.matmul(input_tensor, W_1)
    layer_1 = tf.add(layer_1, B_1)
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)

    #2_layer
    layer_2 = tf.matmul(layer_1, W_2)
    layer_2 = tf.add(layer_2, B_2)
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)

    #output layer
    output = tf.matmul(layer_2, W_output)
    output = tf.add(output, B_output)
    
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        _loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels, output))
        
    grads = tape.gradient(_loss, var_list)
    grads_and_vars = zip(grads, var_list)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
```

Comment: Why not use ```tf.keras``` like this [https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough#define_the_loss_and_gradient_function](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough#define_the_loss_and_gradient_function)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do not post python code as Javascript snippet (edited).

Answer (score 0):

Well, my problem was that I didn't clearly understand how gradients calculation in TF2 works. As for TF1 it was fine to pass a tensor to minimize, for TF2 its needed to pass a callable function in GradientTape.

Here is my code, which  is still very simple but is working properly now.

```
input_shape = x_train.shape[1]
n_hidden_1 = 32
n_hidden_2 = 8
output_shape = 1
epochs = 100

class model():
    def __init__(self, input_tensor, lables):
        self.W_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([input_shape,n_hidden_1]))
        self.W_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_hidden_1,n_hidden_2]))
        self.W_output = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_hidden_2,output_shape]))
        self.B_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_hidden_1]))
        self.B_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_hidden_2]))
        self.B_output = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([output_shape]))    
        self.var_list= [self.W_1, self.W_2, self.W_output, self.B_1, self.B_2, self.B_output]
    
    def train(self):
        layer_1 = tf.matmul(input_tensor, self.W_1)
        layer_1 = tf.add(layer_1, self.B_1)
        layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
        #2_layer
        layer_2 = tf.matmul(layer_1, self.W_2)
        layer_2 = tf.add(layer_2, self.B_2)
        layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
        #output layer
        output = tf.matmul(layer_2, self.W_output)
        output = tf.add(output, self.B_output)   
        return output

    def loss(self, output):
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels, output))
        return loss

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)


input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(x_train, dtype=tf.float32)
size = input_tensor.shape[0]
labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train, dtype=tf.float32)
labels = tf.reshape(labels, (size,1))

model = model(input_tensor, labels)

for epoch in range(epochs):
    
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        output = model.train()
        loss = model.loss(output)
    
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.var_list)
    grads_and_vars = zip(grads, model.var_list)
    opt.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    print(loss)
```

Comment: The code is ugly ...... The best practice is that every layer should inherit from ```tf.keras.layers.Layer``` . Read [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers) for more detail